# SQL Find count of previous consecutive days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hiiya All,

Trying to work out how I can use SQL to tell me how many days an person has worked consecutively before a date.

Source

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Forename | Surname | EMP_Num   | Shift Date |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-09-28 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-09-29 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-09-30 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-10-02 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-10-03 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Bill     | Kerry   | 0112      | 2017-09-28 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Bill     | Kerry   | 0112      | 2017-09-29 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Bill     | Kerry   | 0112      | 2017-10-01 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Bill     | Kerry   | 0112      | 2017-10-02 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Bill     | Kerry   | 0112      | 2017-10-03 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

so the results for today (2017-10-03) will be...

```
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Forename | Surname | EMP_Num   | Days Worked |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2           |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Bill     | Kerry   | 0112      | 3           |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

or result for 2017-09-30 would be

```
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Forename | Surname | EMP_Num   | Days Worked |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 3           |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| Bill     | Kerry   | 0112      | 0           |
+----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

Any Ideas?

I'm running SQL 2008 so no lead or lag I'm afraid.

PS Thanks for http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do it in a single query because of your requirement of consecutive dates. I think you need something more complex like a script or query + code.